# How to get the average fft value of each frequency band?

Tags: python-3.x, fft

Hello everybody I am trying to get the average fft value of my 7 freq bands
This is the code so far. It works with a log function.
The problem is I want the **average fft value** of each band
How can I do this?
Somebody told to get the lower indexes but I can't figure it out 
It's getting quit complicated for me now.
This is the code >>

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import math
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True) # don't use scientific notation

CHUNK = 2048 # number of data points to read at a time
RATE = 44100 # time resolution of the recording device (Hz)


p=pyaudio.PyAudio() # start the PyAudio class
stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=RATE,input=True,
              frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #uses default input device

#maxValue            = 2**16
# 7 Freq Bands

NUM_BAND = 7
lower = 0
d = math.log10(CHUNK/2-1)/NUM_BAND


for i in range(1): #to it a few times just to see
    try:
        data = np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16)
        fft = abs(np.fft.fft(data).real)
        fft = fft[:int(len(fft)/2)] # keep only first half

        freq = np.fft.fftfreq(CHUNK,1.0/RATE)
        freq = freq[:int(len(freq)/2)] # keep only first half


        band_lower = []
        for i in range(NUM_BAND):
            higher = round(math.pow(10,(i+1)*d))
            print("Band %d from freq[%d]=%f to freq[%d]=%f"%(i, lower, 
            freq[lower], higher, freq[higher]))
            lower = higher+1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        p.terminate()
```

And this is the printout

```
Band 0 from freq[0]=0.000000 to freq[3]=64.599609
Band 1 from freq[4]=86.132812 to freq[7]=150.732422
Band 2 from freq[8]=172.265625 to freq[19]=409.130859
Band 3 from freq[20]=430.664062 to freq[52]=1119.726562
Band 4 from freq[53]=1141.259766 to freq[141]=3036.181641
Band 5 from freq[142]=3057.714844 to freq[380]=8182.617188
Band 6 from freq[381]=8204.150391 to freq[1023]=22028.466797
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the average using `np.average`:

`start` and `end` are your bands.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [3,4,5]])

print(np.average(a[start:end], axis=0))
```

Comment: Sorry you could you more specific?
I used the following print(np.average(fft[lower:higher], axis=0)) and print(np.average(fft[band_lower[i]:band_higher[i]], axis=0)) both are printing values on each band while listening to a 1 khz tone, and that isn't correct.

Comment: From what I understand, you want the mean of the interval between the lowest and the highest frequency. Right? If yes, I think this `print(np.average(freq[lower:higher], axis=0))`  work.

Comment: Uhm I want the average fft value from the lowest frequency to the highest frequency of each of the 7 bands

Comment: I have mapped out the frequencies in the second for loop. 
So band0 = freq 0 - freq 65 or something 
I need the average fft value of that freq 0 until freq 65
And that for each band.
Also  print(np.average(freq[lower:higher], axis=0)) doesn't have anything to do with fft values

Comment: Using this print(np.average(fft[lower:higher], axis=0)) prints out 27730.46109762716
28380.534577054885
30601.639974516947
184342.78283237503
14854.994376251167
712.8902501402762
296.21431388256525
Those are values on each band while I am listening to a 1 khz tone.
So that isn't correct